# Energy harvesting using LTC3108 not working

Tags: circuit-design, dc-dc-converter, energy-harvesting

I’m trying to boost the energy of a plant microbial fuel cell (PMFC) using the CJMCU 3108 LTC3108 energy harvester breakout board. I’ve configured it like the image below, for 3.7 V.

[LTC3108 datasheet.](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC3108.pdf)

[image]

I connected everything on a breadboard like the images attached, but when I use a multimeter to measure the voltage out, it doesn’t show a reading:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The PMFC (the energy source) itself has a reading:

[image]

In my research I saw that “if all else fails, solder all the GND connections together.” If that’s what I need to do, how exactly do I go about it?

Below are reference images for the breakout board pins:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to EE. If you have a circuit diagram or schematics that will help, and a link to the datasheet. Otherwise well documented.

Comment: Did you add the 100:1 transformer yourself? It IS oriented correctly, but it's another thing to check if it still doesn't work after you have made the alterations suggested in my answer. ||Interest only questions - answer only if you want to : Where did you get the PMFC - did you make it or ... ? - a fun technology. How many cm^2 area and what power output do you hope to get from it? | Where are you doing this and in what context? | Where did you get the board and what cost?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Regarding the transformer, I gave it to our school's robotics lab for soldering (same for everything else that was soldered on the board). 

|| For your other questions: First of all, thank you for the interest! Yes, I made the pmfc using graphite rods as electrodes. Right now I'm hoping to get enough energy to power simple circuits (like an LED) with the LTC3108. This us for our school research capstone project, we are looking into the viability of concurrent food and energy production. And I got the board from a local seller! ||

Comment: @Mizukukun I understand that PFMC electrodes are usually copper and zinc mesh. How do you get polarity with 2 x graphite rods? || Also - does not power avail;able rise with electrode area? - easily accomplished with mesh but not so easily with graphite rods.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon -- Graphite has a layered structure, and can be used in Supercapacitors [and Lithium-ion batteries](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22graphite+rod%22+%22intercalation%22+Lithium+ion), as the "surface area" internally allows intercalation of Lithium ions. So it's not just the external surface area, but also the internal  surface area as well, chemically available, that matters. But I agree that using the same material as both anode and cathode will not work (but perhaps, if one or both are coated, internally and externally).

Comment: Did you get this to work?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon -- Sorry. I'm not the OP, and I don't have this board.

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD - Yes, I didn't think that you were the OP> They last visited the site two weeks after this post, in early November 2023, so they may never come back. But I posted that in case they ever do.

Answer (score 1):

You have one connection error, and a suspect decision.

The red ellipses show that the jumpers should connect VAUX-VS2 & VS1-GND.
You have "crossed" the connections.
Uncross them :-) .

The green ellipses show that you have used a different ground than they recommend but have ignored their advice re connecting grounds together.  You could use a jumper to join the adjacent grounds where you input voltage connects BUT just moving the jumper to the adjacent ground (as shown on their wiring diagram) is recommended.

[LTC3108 DATASHEET HERE](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC3108.pdf)

---

Added:

Put blue wire at bottom left next to purple - brown wire one hole down- as per diagram.

Connect white jumpers as per diagram and NOT as per how you have them.

Use ohmmeter to test that the transformer's soldering connects as it should and is not shorted between contacts that should not connect.

Ensure solder links between two boards are OK.

Measure voltages relative to ground on 3 inter-pcb links.

[image]

---

Added February 2024:

Confusion has occurred over my use of the term "solder together".
Also over my use of the term "jumper".

"Solder together" has the same meaning as "connect the relevant points to each other electrically using solder".

On a breadboard you may use a "jumper' This is a wire with a plug on each end which is plugged into two points on the breadboard to form a conductive connection between the two points.

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks so much for answering! I adjusted the connections like how you specified (and changed the wires as well just to make sure they weren’t an issue). The reading still isn’t 3.7V though, but for some reason stabilizes at 5.5mV even without the power source plugged in. I checked the multimeter itself and it was fine. Regarding the transformer, the lab didn’t have a heat gun so I assume they just soldered it to the breakout board. Is there a way to know if the transformer is the problem? Also, what do you mean by using a jumper to connect adjacent grounds?

Comment: @Mizukukun  Put blue wire at bottom left next to purple - brown wire one hole down- as per dioagram. || Connect white jumpers as per diagrm and NOT as per how ypu have them. || Use ohmmeter to test that transformer soldering connectrs as it should and is not shorted. || Ensure solder links between two boards is OK.  || Measure voltages relative to ground on 3 inter-pcb links.